# Merge [ranged-attacks-in-close-combat] with [ranged-attacks]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Can we merge [ranged-attacks-in-close-combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranged-attacks-in-close-combat) to [ranged-attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranged-attacks) ?

At this moment we only have one question for it.

Comment: Let me know if there's a more appropriate tag instead of burninate. I can't find merge request or something like that.

Comment: Looks like that tag got removed already.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a situation that can no longer be reproduced; it was already resolved and does not need to be answered anymore.